# How do I get around ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT when accessing a chrome extension with webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I'm not trying to *test* an extension; I just want to run one remotely.  Specifically, I'm trying to back up the OneTab bookmark extension.  It has a feature to export its bookmarks, I'd just like to automate that.

The simplest example I have is this:

```js
import { Builder, until } from "selenium-webdriver";

async function runScript() {
    const browser = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    try {
        await browser.get(
            "chrome-extension://chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall/onetab.html"
        );
        await browser.wait(until.titleIs("webdriver - Google Search"), 5000);
    } finally {
        browser.quit();
    }
}

runScript();
```

Open the page, and see if anything resolves.  When I run this, I get the following message:

```
chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall is blocked
This page has been blocked by Chrome
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

There are a number of sites that talk about related issues with other extensions blocking access, but I've disabled all extensions. The error message itself says this isn't about extensions, but about *Chrome itself* blocking automated access to extension pages. This doesn't seem like that esoteric a request, and I suspect `chromedriver`-driven pages are blocked from accessing a lot of things for security reasons, but this is blocking progress on a simple script.

Any help?

Comment: `onetab.html` must be added to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

Comment: I don't think that's helpful; I can't change the manifest file without damaging the fingerprint, which means Chrome will stop loading the extension entirely.